# I would like to publicly share the details of my investment portfolio. What websites add value in this regard?

Tags: investing, etf, portfolio, financial-advisor

I want to have the ability to share the details of my holdings and have a website track the return over time while making this information 100% public to anyone who may be interested. What websites provide this capability?

Answer (score 4):

This is going to be a bit of a shameless plug, but I've build a portfolio tracking website to track your portfolio and be able to share it (in read-only mode) as  well.

It is at http://frano.carelessmusings.com and currently in beta.

Most portfolio trackers are behind a login wall and thus will lack the sharing function you are looking for. Examples of these are: Yahoo Finance, Google Finance, Reuters Portfolios, MorningStart Portfolios, and many others.

Another very quick and easy solution (if you are not trading too often) is a shared google docs spreadsheet. Gdocs has integration with google finance and can retrieve prices for stocks by symbol. A spreadsheet can contain the following:

Symbol, Quantity, Avg. Buy Price, Price, P/L, P/L% and so on.

The current price and P/L data can be functions that use the google finance API.

Hope this helps, and if you check out my site please let me know what you think and what I could change.

Comment: +1  Thanks for disclosing your association with the site. :)   Also, I upvoted because not only did you list your solution and an alternative (google docs), but discussed issues with other portfolio sites.

Comment: @AlexB Your site seems to be down. Is your test platform up elsewhere and would it by chance support stock options too?

Comment: @Marcos, I think you meant to contact Gennadly.   It is their site, not mine.  I just made a comment.